# Is there a way to print a Groovy Collection out in a pastable format?

Tags: collections, groovy, format

I routinely have to mock some data responses for unit testing purposes. I'd like to be able to collect a real response and put it in a mock. But Groovy prints out Collections without enclosing the string values.

```
def foo = ["foo":"bar"]
println foo
def bar = ["foo","bar"]
println bar
```

returns

```
[foo:bar]
[foo, bar]
```

So when I have a huge and complex json structure to work with I have to spend a long time in tedious and error prone editing. I could probably write a recursive function to print this for me but I was curious if there was a trivial way to do it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for **trivial** datatypes there is [`inspect`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#inspect%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
def m = [a:'a', b:42, c:[1,2,3]]
def d = m.inspect()
assert d=='''['a':'a', 'b':42, 'c':[1, 2, 3]]'''
m2 = Eval.me(d)
assert m==m2
```

Comment: Ah, most Excellent! I knew there was a lazy way.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no easy way, however You can implement it Yourself. An a hoc solution:

```
class L extends LinkedList {
    String toString() {
        '[' + collect { "'$it'" }.join(',') + ']'
    }
}

def l = new L()
l << 1
l << 2
assert l.toString() == "['1','2']"
```

When it comes to JSON `JsonOutput` class produces pastable output:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson([a:1]))

new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('''{
    "a": 1
}''')
```

Comment: `'[' + list.collect { "'$it'" }.join(',') + ']'` is easier no?

Comment: groovy.json.JsonOutput makes sense. I can just reslurp the json back into a Groovy Map in my test class.